# Draw a circle when we have improvement in line plot in MATLAB R2014b

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-guide

Suppose that my GUI (Designed with GUIDE) automatically upgrade a plot like this :

[image]

I want have circle or something like that in improvement steps:

[image]

How we can do this in MATLAB R2014b?

**PS.**

I'm using a code like this for updating the plot in GUI:

```
plot(handles.plot,Value); %%(In a loop)
```

`Value` is updating in a loop.

Comment: How does the data look like that you plot? Can you provide the part of code that generates the plot?

Comment: @hitzg I add more information.

Comment: @user2991243 so does any answer helped you solve your problem? If so please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following to detect the points where the function 'improves', i.e. when the derivative changes, and plot the points at the corresponding locations:

```
clear
close all
clc


%// Generate dummy data
t = 1:10;
y = zeros(size(t));

idx1 = 0 <= t & t <= 2;
y(idx1) = 2*t(idx1);

idx2 = 2 < t & t < 3;
y(idx2) = t(idx2);

idx3 = 3 <= t & t <= 5;
y(idx3) = 4;

idx4 = 5 <= t & t <= 8;
y(idx4) = 2*t(idx4);

idx5 = 8 <= t & t <= 10;
y(idx5) = 8;
%======

%// Get indices corrsponding to change in curve
CircleIndices = t(diff(diff(y)) ~= 0) +1

%// Get y-coordinates
yC = y(CircleIndices)

%// plot the curve + the circles
plot(t,y,'r')
hold on
scatter(CircleIndices,yC,40,'k','filled')
hold off
```

which looks like this:

[image]

that's pretty easy to implement in your loop/callback. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a circle over every data point do the following:

```
h = plot(handles.plot,Value,'.-');
set(h,'MarkerSize',20,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0 0]);
```

the second line will set the size and color of the dots, experiment to give them the size you want.

If you want to plot dots over some specific data points do this:

```
plot(handles.plot,Value);
hold on
h = plot(specific_X,specific_Y,'.');
set(h,'MarkerSize',20,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0 0]);
```

where specific_X and specific_Y are vectors with the x and y of the data points you want to plot the dots.

Answer (score 1):

@R. Schifini wrote a good answer if you already know the desired points. This answer will be good if you want it automatic:

I understood that you add data to the plot inside the loop iteratively (But truly it seems that you just run over the previous plot...). If so, you can write it like that:

```
plot(handles.plot,Value); %%(In a loop)
if (Value(end)-Value(end-1))~=(Value(end-1)-Value(end-2))  %% if the slope is changing
  hold on; plot(handles.plot(end-1),Value(end-1), 'ko','Markersize',15);
end
```